# Keep results recurring

Tags: pytorch

```
from torch_geometric.nn import GATConv
 random.seed(seed)
    os.environ['PYTHONHASHSEED'] = str(seed)
    np.random.seed(seed)
    torch.manual_seed(seed)
    torch.cuda.manual_seed(seed)
    torch.cuda.manual_seed_all(seed)
    torch_geometric.seed=seed
a=GATConv(args.gat_layer1_out_dim * args.nheads,int(args.fpn_out_dim * 2 * args.ratio),1, dropout=args.gnn_dropout,).to(args.device)
b=a(input)
print(b)
```

why this class result different every run?

how to stay the same?